# how to download videos in user machine Django

Tags: python, django, download, youtube

Here is my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse,redirect
import youtube_dl
from django.contrib import messages
from pytube import *

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')


def download(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        video_url = request.POST.get('url')
        if video_url:
            ydl_opts = {'outtmp1': 'D:/'}
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([video_url])
            messages.success(request, 'Video Downloaded.')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Please Enter Video URL')
            return redirect('home')
        return redirect('home')
```

How can I download the video file to the user's machine?
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your program that the generated link is not brought back to home.html

Just Like below code

```
def some_view(request):
                    
    context = {}
    load_template      = "home.html"
    context['segment'] = load_template
    context['url'] = {YOUR_URL}
    html_template = loader.get_template( load_template )
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

In addition, you should first store the generated file in a space that can be accessed by the user, and then return the URL of the file to the user

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

def download_pdf(request):
    filename = 'whatever_in_absolute_path__or_not.pdf'
    content = FileWrapper(filename)
    response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'whatever_name_will_appear_in_download.pdf'
    return response
```

You can use this for any file type.